# How to use treeTable reveal function?

Tags: jquery, plugins, treetable

I use the [treeTable plugin](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/#introduction)   to create and manipulate a tree control. I've assigned classes to the different levels of the tree. For the lowest level, I have several nodes with the same class.

I'm trying to use the API's reveal function, but have it only half-working. These examples work on one node only:

```
$("#gq-report-list tr.er-level-4.child-of-tmpl-1").reveal(); // Works for one node
$("#gq-report-list tr.er-level-4").reveal(); // Works for one node
$("#gq-report-list").find(".er-level-4").closest('tr').reveal(); // Works for one node
$("#gq-report-list").find(".owner-shared").closest('tr').reveal(); // Works for one node
```

I need to reveal several nodes based on the find result. In this snippet, there are 9 nodes to reveal, but only the first node is:

```
rows = $("#gq-report-list").find(".private"); // Works for one node, but there are 9
alert(rows.length);
rows.closest('tr').reveal();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#yourtreetable").treetable("reveal", "id");
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.